# Load image from internal memory

Tags: java, android, opencv

i'm having problem in loading image coming from the internal storage of my android phone. I want to load the image and use it for grabcut segmentation. 
I tried using this code

```
  File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"pic.jpg");
     ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);  
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

But everytime I run the app on my phone the application suddenly stopped. Can I ask for help and know what's wrong in my code? Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

What is the error you get? Find out in the debug. I tried to run your code and the path I get is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../filespic.jpg so I would say try to change

```
+"pic.jpg");
```

in

```
+"/pic.jpg");
```

and

```
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

to show image.